# Solve complex equation $(z-i)^4=(1+2i)^8.$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following equation to solve:
$$(z-i)^4=(1+2i)^8.$$
I have already tried using polar form of those numbers, but that leads to nothing. I'm looking for the shortest way to find the answer.

Comment: Take fourth roots. $z-i = (1+2i)^2\cdot w$, where $w$ is a fourth root of 1.

Comment: It's also worth noting that $(1+2i)^2=-3+4i.$

Answer (score 1):

$$\left(\dfrac{z-i}{(1+2i)^2}\right)^4=1=e^{2m\pi i}$$ where $m$ is any integer

$$\implies\dfrac{z-i}{(1+2i)^2}=e^{2m\pi i/4}=\cos\dfrac{m\pi}2+i\sin\dfrac{m\pi}2$$ where $m\equiv0,1,2,3\pmod4$